# Automate Windows FTP Server installation using Powershell 2.0 32 bit version

Tags: powershell, automation, ftp

We have around 300 "boxes" (servers) all 32bit processors running Win2K8 R2 - and on which we need to install Windows FTP server. The infra team is trying to run a powershell script (https://4sysops.com/archives/install-and-configure-an-ftp-server-with-powershell/) to automate this via a job later.

The trouble is that all the boxes have Powershell V2.0 32 bit and to be able to do this you need to have the "server-manager" module which is not available / wont run with 32bit version.

We have a constraint that we can't update all the 300 boxes on short notice with missing windows features / update windows features ( for ex. WMF 5.1).

Is there any workaround to make do with the Powershell 32bit commandlets ?

Comment: Windows component installation questions are off-topic at SO, since those aren't programming issues. Anyway, you _really_ should migrate to more recent version of Windows.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Its more related to powershell and if I can get it to run 64bit commandlets in the above constraints. But thanks anyway.